# Return Key and JSON String from SQL 2016 Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Using SQL 2016 JSON built in functions

Table: Users
Columns (ID int, FirstName varchar(50), LastName varchar(50)

Data

`3009    Emily        Manners
3010    Joanne       Hernandez
3011    Kelly        Kleiner
3012    Alexis       Frederick
3013    Dietric      Singleton
3018    Ashley       Ely
3021    Jeralynn     Campbell-Triplett
3026    Lauren       Zinnerman
3027    Christopher  Correa
3028    Stefanie     MontalvoCruz`

Desired results -> temp table

```
ID       JSON_DATA        
3009    {"ID":3009,"FirstName":"Emily","LastName":"Manners"}
3010    {"ID":3010,"FirstName":"Joanne","LastName":"Hernandez"}
```

Trying to use:

```
SELECT
    [ID],
    [FirstName],
    [LastName]
FROM Emp
FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of a CROSS APPLY

```
Declare @Emp table (ID int,FirstName varchar(50),LastName varchar(50))
Insert into @Emp values
(3009,'Emily' ,'Manners'),
(3010,'Joanne','Hernandez'),
(3011,'Kelly' ,'Kleiner')

Select A.ID
      ,B.JSON_Data
 From @Emp A
 Cross Apply (
               Select JSON_Data = (Select A.ID,A.FirstName,A.LastName FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)
             ) B
```

Returns

```
ID      JSON_Data
3009    {"ID":3009,"FirstName":"Emily","LastName":"Manners"}
3010    {"ID":3010,"FirstName":"Joanne","LastName":"Hernandez"}
3011    {"ID":3011,"FirstName":"Kelly","LastName":"Kleiner"}
```

Comment: Heya John http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138432/room-for-sqlzim-and-john-cappelletti

Answer (score 0):

This form may be more readable than using cross apply in some circumstances.
In cases I've tried execution plans are always identical but one may perform better than the other in any given situation.

```
Declare @Emp table (ID int,FirstName varchar(50),LastName varchar(50))
Insert into @Emp values
(3009,'Emily' ,'Manners'),
(3010,'Joanne','Hernandez'),
(3011,'Kelly' ,'Kleiner')

Select A.ID
      ,(Select A.ID,A.FirstName,A.LastName 
           FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES, 
           WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) AS JSON_Data
 From @Emp A
```